# Is it possible to determinate if an element is currently overflowing its container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if a horizontal scrollbar is applied to a div like this:

```
if (box.width() < box.get(0).scrollWidth)
```

This is always true, even when there isn't any scrollbar, because `box.get(0).scrollWidth` returns `203px`, while `.width()` returns `200`.

Here I have an example, please look at the first box. `$('.box0')`

Example : http://www.nikolaydyankov.com/Dev/lionbars/

Comment: what browsers is this reproducible?

Comment: I get 183 for width and scrollWidth in FF 8.0.1. What browser are you testing under?

Comment: strange, I'm getting 200 and 203. Are you selecting .box0 ?

Comment: I'm also getting 200/203 in Chrome. Also `.clientWidth` is 203, whereas `.width()` returns 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just this to determine if a div is overflowing - ie scrollable :

```
$.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
    var _elm = $(this)[0];
    var _hasScrollBar = false; 
    if ((_elm.clientHeight < _elm.scrollHeight) || (_elm.clientWidth < _elm.scrollWidth)) {
        _hasScrollBar = true;
    }
    return _hasScrollBar;
}
```

usage : `$('#<id>').hasScrollBar();` returns true / false

*from SO originally I think

Comment: Both clientWidth and scrollWidth return 203. Thanks, this should work. I should read more about clientWidth.

Comment: You also have to check if the scrollbar is visible, even though it is disabled. That is overflow: scroll